# Cat Toy(s) For Energetic Cat

Tags: cats, toys, exercise

One of our cats (male, 3yo) is very energetic and almost dog-like, personally I love it!  Our other cat (female, same age) is quite the opposite, she is far more sedentary and gets quite annoyed when our male cat tries to chase after her and play with her.

That said, does anyone have suggestions (store bought or homemade) for cat toys that would both entertain and exercise our male cat such that he might not have as much of a tendency to chase our other cat around.

Any/all suggestions are appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: How much time do/can you spend playing with them? A lot of this has to be experimentation:, since different cats like different toys. A ribbon or string works for many, but I need to make sure it's a fairly strong one or Harry will try to chew it into pieces and eat it.

Comment: @keshlam Hey there! We spend about 45 minutes a day playing with them on weekends but significantly less during the weeks.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options I can think of:

1. [Wireless cat mice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RTDNI64) - this one you can control
2. [HEXBUG mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SQXVF7A) - this one moves on its own
3. [Petsafe Pounce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FZF3OEO) - mouse moves randomly in a circle
4. [Petsafe lazer toy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0021L8W6K) - lazer moves around for you
5. [Petsafe food dispenser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0018CE8LG) - Ball you put food in and the cat has to bounce it around to get the food out.
6. [Exercise wheel for cats](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NFZMHKS) - Will need some training for it - hamster wheel for cats!
7. [Cat Towers](https://www.petsmart.com/cat/supplies-and-training/furniture-and-scratchers/) - great for climbing
8. [Catnip](https://www.petmd.com/blogs/thedailyvet/jcoates/2011/june/cats_and_catnip-does_it_really_get_them_high_and_why-11271) - Sprinkle catnip on a towel and watch him roll around!

Toys to avoid are ones with string or elastics, cats tend to swallow these things giving you an expensive surgery to prepare for.

Comment: From experience, different cats like different things. After all the toys we got our cats (and they have different tastes), all three of them think that a rope (like you can pull from a hoodie) is the **best. toy. ever.** They (non-violently) fight over it and continually steal it from each other's spots. You'll have to try different toys and see what sticks :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Rebecca RVT's excellent suggestions, I would recommend almost any container or packing materials.Cats are notorious for their love of boxes!I can say without hesitation, my many cats over the years have virtually always chosen "free" cat toys like boxes or any kind of ball-of-something; paper, foil, string and anything they can bat around over expensive cat amusements.

My favorite solution for an active, young cat: A cardboard box, the corrugated packing material (for scratching), a ball of paper and any high place they can easily access. Everywhere I've lived, I've always added some carpeted shelves above the fray where my kitties could feel safe and "hunter-y."

Above all, make certain he has access to attention, affection and somewhere to be "above it all." Good luck!

Comment: Oh yes, boxes are a huge hit for our energetic cat!  He will climb inside them, do a little clawing at them and turn them into little forts.  The corrugated idea is great, he would love to scratch at it and play, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck and remember, cats seem to love the stuff we want to throw away while ignoring the toys we spend small fortunes on.

Answer (score 3):

I think good toys are in the eye of the cat. I have a bunch of bought toys that my cat plays with sometimes (his favorite being a tube looking stuffed animal thing with a feather on the end), but his absolute favorite things to play with are just random things he finds around the house. He loves crumpled receipts and he will find the most random ones to bring to his little stash. He takes pieces of cardboard and even big boxes and bats them around at all (and I mean all) hours of the day. He also steals plastic bags a lot, so I have to either put them up high or cut the handles so he doesn't choke himself. He has a knack for finding little things like twist ties that I accidentally drop, then he stores them for later in places I don't know about or can't reach.

I think it is really up to the cat. Personally, the toys I buy are feathered ones because I noticed my cat seems to lick them when I'm not home like he is grooming them. I also get a few of those string toys with fluff on a string attached to a stick that he likes and I like, because those tire my cat out the most. They are pretty easy to absentmindedly wave while watching a movie or something, too. I would suggest just getting a decent amount of different cheap toys and give your cats a "play area" in your house where they can choose what they want to do. If you have an energetic cat, you personally should spend more time exercising it, just like a dog.

Answer (score 2):

My cat loves to chase and bat around those little plastic balls with bells on them. In fact she loves anything that has feathers on it or bells whether it be fake mice or bells or a string toy. She also loves plastic lids or cups. I think she likes the sound they make while on our tile kitchen floor. My cats two favorite toys are a turbo cat scratcher (a circle toy that has a ball that she can bat around and a scratcher circle in the middle that is replaceable. She spends 30 minutes or so playing on it and loves it at night as I replaced the ball with one that glows.

Another one of her favorites is the hot pursuit concealed toy (The cat's meow). I got the idea to buy it for her as she attacks my legs under the blankets. It's a toy that acts just like something moving under a blanket. She simply loves the thing and can spend a good bit of time on it.

My cat also has fallen in love with the laser pointer and will even carry it to a person and drop it on their lap (much like a dog does to an owner with their leash).

Answer (score 0):

Staying active is such a necessary thing for your cat’s health. Playing games that are stimulating, help to reduce anxiety, stress levels and can help to eliminate behavioral problems. Because they are natural predators, from time to time they will need to turn on their natural problem solving instincts. The games that can help to do this, will build your cat’s confidence; especially games they are able to walk away from feeling like a winner.

Comment: Please put a list of options here if / when the link goes dead.